# How to make a Class return an object when the class is referenced after it has been initialized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

How to make a class return an object in the following way:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1,2),(3,4)])
```

Whenever `a` is referenced, it returns

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

However when I create a simple class:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.nparray = np.array(data)
```

And run `b = Example([(1,2),(3,4)])` then reference `b` I get: `<__main__.Example at 0x7f17381099e8>`. To return the value I need to run `b.nparray`.

How to make the class `Example` return

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

when `b` is referenced?

I tried using methods such as `__new__`, `__repr__` and `__getitem__` however none produced the desired behavior.

Comment: _"Whenever `a` is called, it returns..."_ Huh? It doesn't return that on my machine. When I execute your first code block and then do `a()`, I get `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`.

Comment: That's not what classes are for, or what "call" means.

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting - OP is just confused on terminology. **Calling** means this: `a()`, but when you say you're "calling" `a` you mean you're just referencing `a`.

Comment: My bad, thanks for clearing that up, I'll edit the post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `__repr__` in the following way:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, data):
            self.nparray = np.array(data)
    def __repr__(self):
            return repr(self.nparray)
```

This returns the representation the `self.nparray` object within:

```
>>> c = Example([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
>>> c
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Of course this is used **and** during interactive sessions where you simply enter the name and press enter and if you print it with `print(c)`. If you need to limit to only for `print` calls you define `__str__` for the object in question.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing `repr()` when I tried using `__repr__`.

Answer (score 2):

Using Python's "magic methods", like the `__init__` you've already seen, we can make the class execute code when certain things happen. One of these is `__call__`, which executes when the class is called like a function.

Knowing this, you could use this code:

```
import numpy as np

class Example:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.nparray = np.array(data)

    def __call__(self):
        # This function is called when an instance of Example is called
        return self.nparray
```

The result of this:

```
>>> b = Example([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> b()
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

For more on magic methods, see [this useful article](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html).

Comment: This works great if OP literally calls the Example instance he creates, as in `b = Example(...); print(b())`. But I think OP is using an unusual definition of "call" that means something more like "when I enter `b` on a line by itself in the interactive interpreter". So he wants `b = Example(...); print(b)` to show the array.

Comment: @kevin That's true. I'll leave the answer here anyway for future Googlers.

Comment: Unfortunately `__call__` does not seem to work with numpy objects. It seems to still return `<__main__.Example at 0x7fc23007f898>`.

Comment: @Dave Please read my comment on your main post; you've referred to "calling" things when you're just accessing them, leading to answers like mine that don't do what you want. Jim's answer seems to do what you want.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 I am looking further into `__call__` and hope that you might be able to clear something up. If another method is added to Example: `def  transpose(self):;    self.nparray = self.nparray.T;`, when I assign a new variable `c` using `c = b()`, then `id(c) == id(b())` is True. Once `b.transpose()` is executed however `id(c) == id(b())` is False. Why is this? wasn't `c` simply a pointer to `b()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't return any data from a class **init** function. Have you tried something like:

```
class Example(object):
    nparray = None
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.nparray = np.array(data)
        return

    def getArray(self):
        return(self.nparray)
```

Comment: This returns `<__main__.Example at 0x7f2fdd455240>` when a is referenced.